# Unable to call function using python-telegram-bot in ConversationHandler

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

In my code when the bot is triggered the function `user_exist()` is triggered. If returns False, the function `new_account()` is triggered and works perfectly, instead, when returns True, it should trigger the function `wallet_handler()`, but it can't. The code is running in a Conversation Handler. I thought I did everything fine, but I can't figure out why the function `wallet_handler()` is not triggered. Anyone can help me? This is my code:

```
import logging
import data
from web3 import Web3
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, Update
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CommandHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    Filters,
    ConversationHandler,
    CallbackContext,
    CallbackQueryHandler,
)

NEW_ACCOUNT, WALLET_HANDLER= range(2)

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    chatid = update.message.chat_id

    if data.user_exist(chatid) == True:
        print('s')
        return WALLET_HANDLER
    if data.user_exist(chatid) == False:
        update.message.reply_text('This is your first time with us! Please insert a wallet')  
        return NEW_ACCOUNT


def new_account(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    chatid = update.message.chat_id
    wallet = update.message.text

    if Web3.isAddress(wallet) == True:
        data.new_account(chatid, wallet)
        update.message.reply_text('New account succesfully created.\nWelcome to Tarsier. Enjoy it!')
        return WALLET_HANDLER
    else:
        update.message.reply_text('Wallet Address invalid.\nPlease insert a valid Wallet Address.')
        return NEW_ACCOUNT
    

def wallet_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    update.message.reply_text('aaa')
    return ConversationHandler.END

def cancel(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    """Cancels and ends the conversation."""
    user = update.message.from_user
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Bye! I hope we can talk again some day.', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    )

    return ConversationHandler.END


def main() -> None:
    """Run the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("TOKEN")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Add conversation handler with the states GENDER, PHOTO, LOCATION and BIO
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            NEW_ACCOUNT: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, new_account)],
            WALLET_HANDLER: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, wallet_handler)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
    )

    dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the check_update function to determine in which state the conversation is.

New user state 0
Existing user state 1

https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html#telegram.ext.ConversationHandler.check_update

Comment: Could you show how you would edit my code in order to use the check_update ?